# C# Mongodb find first by comparing field values

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to get back the first record in which I am comparing 2 field values in the same record, but am getting back an ArgumentException {"Unsupported where clause: (x.CharCount != x.Body.Length)."}

Any suggestions on how to correct this?
Updated:
    The end result would be to get the first record where the charcount field does not equal the length of the body field.  Is there a way to do this with and query and not need to use a lambda expresion?

```
post = collection.AsQueryable<Post>().First(x => x.CharCount != x.Body.Length);
```

here are the class structures

```
class Post
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int CharCount { get; set; }
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like string.length == int value is not supported on database side. Try getting the values from the db and write your query like this:

```
post = db.GetCollection<Post>().Linq().First(x => x.CharCount != x.Body.Length);
```

Comment: This still kicks back the same exception.  There has to be a way to do this.  I wonder if there is better way to write the query with out a lambda expression?